# How can I get a list of files of two different types in a directory using PHP?

Tags: php

I need to get `*.m4v` AND `*.mp4` files.

This is what I use to get one file type. What code should I use to get a list of BOTH types?

```
//get all image files with a .m4v extension.
$images = glob($directory . "*.m4v");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in the `glob(`) manual page:

```
$images = glob($directory . "*.{m4v,mp4}", GLOB_BRACE);
```

Comment: 100% correct, but might be worth mentioning, that this has two pitfalls: 1. On Unixes, you might want `"*.{m4v, M4V,mp4,MP4}"` to deal with windows uploads, that have an uppercase suffix and 2. on windows, `glob()` might be severely broken, depending on OS and PHP version

Comment: Yes.  You can use character classes but I've never tried them in braces: `*.[mM]4[vV]` - Not tested: `*.{[mM]4[vV],[mM][pP]4}`